# How to hide and show panel multiple times in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I am trying to catch all updates in grid and want to show message with html config in panel docked at bottom in grid. If I click on one button show preview then this message panel will be hide.

This is working fine but when I click on show preview button multiple times.
and edit some field from grid then dom of message panel is getting as null. throwing an error `TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.insertBefore is not an object.`
I am using extjs 6 version.

EDIT : Hi.
Here is my code to hide/show panel and changing message from panel as per condition.

```
var notePanel = Ext.getCmp("notePanelContainer");

if(ispropertyupdate) {
    notePanel.update("Property panel has been updated."); 
} else {
    notePanel.update("Fields grid has been updated."); 
}
if(ishide){
    notePanel.hide();
}else{
    notePanel.show();
}
```

Comment: Add your code, please.

Comment: Hi @Sergey Novikov . I have added my code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly doing, but I created this [simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1chh) to illustrate solution for your task (at least as I understand it).

*As I understand you use [Ext.panel.Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html) as docked item to show your message, its too heavy component for this task. Use something like [Ext.Component](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.Component.html).*